# Add count labels to clustered bar graph ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tend to struggle with adding labels to bar graphs. I am trying to add count labels next to each bar in this graph, but the numbers are not placed in the right spot:

[image: bargraph]

Here is my data (a subset of a bigger dataset):

```
County  Group   Plan1   Plan2
County1 Group3  597     513
County2 Group3  182     130
County3 Group3  180     126
County4 Group3  266     284
County5 Group3  258     171
County6 Group3  159     71
County7 Group3  187     157
County8 Group3  101     84
```

I tried to use geom_text() suggestions from other posts, but kept getting similar results.

Code:

```
df.g <- gather(df, key=`Plan Type`, value=value, -County, -Group)

ggplot(df.g[df.g$Group == "Group3", ], 
       aes(County, value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = `Plan Type`), 
           stat = "identity", colour = "black", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") + 
  ggtitle("Enrollees per Plan by County") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(x = County, y = value, label = value, 
                hjust = ifelse(sign(value) > 0, 1, 0)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

How can I add count labels correctly to this graph? Thank you for any advice/suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)

df.g <- gather(df, 
#personal preference: avoid using variable names with spaces; looks cleaner that way.
               key = Plan.Type, 
               value = value, 
               -County, -Group)

ggplot(filter(df.g, Group == "Group3"),
       aes(x = County, y = value, 
           fill = Plan.Type,
           label = value)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            hjust = 0) +
  # + other title / theme options
  coord_flip()
```

[image: plot]